# Accessing files within contained directories

Tags: bash, directory, subdirectory

If I were to try to change the permissions of a specific file type in a directory, for example

```
    chmod ugo-w *.filetype
```

How can I do this for all files in the contained directories as well?

Answer (score 2):

Use find and xargs:

```
find . -type f -name '*.filetype' | xargs chmod ugo-w
```

Replace `.` with the name of the directory, if it is not the current one.

Or, just use `find`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.filetype' -exec chmod ugo-w '{}' '+'
```